# Woocommerce API with React on different ports

Tags: reactjs, api, woocommerce

I want to connect my React app with Woocommerce API. I use this https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api-js-lib package.

The problem is, when I try to make an API GET request, I get an 404 error. I believe because the React app is on port 3000 and Woocommerce API is on port 80.

I tried to specify the port on API initialization:

```
const api = new WooCommerceRestApi({
  url: 'deltaeng',
  consumerKey: 'ck_###',
  consumerSecret: 'cs_###',
  port: '80'
});
```

But I couldn't get rid of this error. Is there any way to use this package to make requests to API from React app?